# Inserting a new image removes blank lines

Tags: bug, images

I find it annoying that inserting a new image removes blank lines. Would it be possible to prevent this behavior?

Example:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is worth fixing (in what practical scenario do you need that much whitespace that does... nothing?), but as a side note, please tag carefully - I happened to see this, but if you want a dev to notice a problem report, [bug] or [feature-request] is the way to go. [discussion] is quite likely to get overlooked.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks, I wasn't sure whether it was by design. In the whitespace I plan to write text :)

Comment: It *might* be by design. The good news is that we have a tag for that. :) I'd have to re-acquaint myself with how image insertion works to know for sure. Having said that... still not sure on the use case here. You'd have to either remove or ignore the blank lines to fill in other text anyway... or your keyboard has the Insert key jammed. ;) Why add a bunch of blank lines as a placeholder?

Comment: @AdamLear I sometimes write messages in a non-sequential way: I have a script that adds 10 blank lines by default, then I jump back and forth between paragraphs.

Comment: Fair enough... but I suspect you're well in the minority there by the time a custom script is involved.

Comment: @AdamLear Maybe we need a minority badge ;-)

Comment: Or a new tag [tag:status-too-minor]... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case we want "too localised" back as a close reason.

Comment: I guess the main question is why doing something that the user never asks for.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see how closing the question would help.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I never suggested such a thing.